# regex and sed command to match relative path filename

Tags: regex, bash, sed, osx-mountain-lion

I'm struggling to create a sed regex command to change lines like this:

```
In file included from dira/file_a.h:8, dire/file_e.h:9, and dirf/file_f.h:10,
             from dirb/file_b.h:6,
             from /existing/abs/path/dirb/file_b.cc:6:
dirc/file_c.h:88: error: 'eqn_count_t' does not name a type
dirc/file_c.h:95: error: 'wave_count_t' does not name a type
dirc/file_c.h:104: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'WmHyperbolicEqnSet' with no type
```

To this **desired output**:

```
In file included from /abspaths/dira/file_a.h:8, /abspaths/dire/file_e.h:9, and /abspaths/dirf/file_f.h:10,
             from /abspaths/dirb/file_b.h:6,
             from /existing/abs/path/dirb/file_b.cc:6:
/abspaths/dirc/file_c.h:88: error: 'eqn_count_t' does not name a type
/abspaths/dirc/file_c.h:95: error: 'wave_count_t' does not name a type
/abspaths/dirc/file_c.h:104: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'WmHyperbolicEqnSet' with no type
```

so,

- only match relative path+filenames that end in .h
- do not match lines that start with a forward-slash (and thus are already absolute paths)
- match multiple occurances per line
- It has become apparent that I need a command that works with **Mac OS X**'s BSD sed command.

**What is the regex and sed command that I want?**

I'm trying to modify gcc output because included header files with errors/warnings generate error stream output with the relative path referenced, not absolute path.  With my XCode IDE calling an external build system, the errors occurring in .h files are not 'clickable'.

Comment: The title doesn't match your question. `/abspath/dirb/file_b.cc` is not at the beginning of line, and it does not end with `.h`

Comment: oops, you're right. i don't care about beginning of line and will edit the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac and Linux friendly:

```
sed -E 's/^([^/][a-zA-Z/_]+\.h)/\/abspaths\/\1/;s/ ([^/][a-zA-Z/_]+\.h)/ \/abspaths\/\1/g' file
```

Matches desired output:

```
In file included from /abspaths/dira/file_a.h:8, /abspaths/dire/file_e.h:9, and /abspaths/dirf/file_f.h:10,
             from /abspaths/dirb/file_b.h:6,
             from /existing/abs/path/dirb/file_b.cc:6:
/abspaths/dirc/file_c.h:88: error: 'eqn_count_t' does not name a type
/abspaths/dirc/file_c.h:95: error: 'wave_count_t' does not name a type
/abspaths/dirc/file_c.h:104: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'WmHyperbolicEqnSet' with no type
```

**Explanation:**

Two substitution are required to account for the extra space needed when the replacement isn't at the start of the line:

```
s/^([^/][a-zA-Z/_]+\.h)/\/abspaths\/\1/;   # First substitution for start of line 
s/ ([^/][a-zA-Z/_]+\.h)/ \/abspaths\/\1/g  # Second for non-start of line

# Match (first substitution)
s/
^             - start of line
(             - capture group 
[^/]          - not a forward slash 
[a-zA-Z/_]+   - one or more letter, forward slash or underscore
\.h           - the extension (escaped) 
)             - end capture group 
# Replace with 
/
\/abspaths\/  - the literal string /abspaths (slashes escaped)
\1            - the captured group 
/;
# Match (second substitution)
s/
' '           - not start of line but a single space (used quotes here for space)
(             - capture group 
[^/]          - not a forward slash 
[a-zA-Z/_]+   - one or more letter, forward slash or underscore
\.h           - the extension (escaped) 
)             - end capture group 
# Replace with 
/
' '           - put the single space back
\/abspaths\/  - the literal string /abspaths (slashes escaped)
\1            - the captured group 
/g            - global flag
```

---

Or just by doing one substitution (based on [**F.Hauri**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095269/regex-and-sed-command-to-match-relative-path-filename/14095646#14095646)) answer however will only work for one match per line:

```
sed -E 's/^(.* )?([^/][^ ]+\.h)/\1\/abspath\/\2/' file
```

For multiple matches `sed` supports [branching](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-6-examples-for-sed-branching-operation/#more-2903):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^(.* )?([^/][^ ]+\.h)/\1\/abspath\/\2/;ta' file
```

Comment: output looks great, but not working for me relating to my comments to @Lev.  I don't have a -r option.  When I did \( \) no matches / substitutions occur.  any ideas?

Comment: thanks, I tried your edit, as well as a version using -E and no escapes before the parentheses.  No matches occurred...

Comment: close.  I ran on my edited test strings.  On line three, I get `from /abspaths//existing/abs/path/dirb/file_b.h:6,` so the double `//` is undesired.

Comment: Thank you! Working for me too.  It would be great if you could add a little explanation to your answer.  Your latest edit expression became quite long.  (also, I'm wondering if your linux-friendly version has been fully tested with the latest test input?)

Comment: I've added an explanation please +1 if you found my answer helpful.

Comment: For more than one match per line, you mean something like `sed -E -e :a -e 's/^(.* )?([^/][^ ]+\.h)/\1\/abspath\/\2/' -e ta testfile.txt` ?

Comment: @F.Hauri I don't know what `-e :a -e` or `-e ta` does but because the match is anchored to the start of line you can only replace one `dira/file.h` per line.

Comment: @sudo_O: No, you're wrong! Try it whith duplicated lines in testfile (`sed -e '4s/^.*$/& &/' -i testfile.txt`) this work (on both linux and mac): `-e :a` is a branch label and `-e ta` is a conditional jump (to `a`) while precedent regex matched.

Comment: @F.Hauri very nice! Thanks for the info.

Comment: @sudo_O: if only on Linux (GNU sed), this could by written; `:a;s/...//;ta`. The need of many `-e` is *standard* GNU sed allow command separation by semi-colon (`;`).

Answer (score 3):

**Last edit**

I've finally successfully created such a command working on both, with only 1 command:

```
sed 's/^\(.* \)\{0,1\}\([^/ ][^ ]\{1,99\}\.h\)/\1\/abspath\/\2/;' testfile.txt
```

And for supporting multi match... even on Mac too (whith some simplifications ideas from @sudo_O):

```
sed -E -e :a -e 's/^(.* )?([^/][^ ]+\.h)/\1\/abspath\/\2/' -e ta testfile.txt
```

But Mac's implementation of `sed` dont support `;` as command separators. So we need to use multiple `-e` command fields.

For testing them, I've modified `textfile.txt` with the following command:

```
sed -e '4s/^.*$/& &/' -i.bak testfile.txt
```

(work on Mac too)

there is two parts, first could countain any string, but ending with a space... 0 or 1 time. Second part must not begin with a space nor a slash, could contain anything but no space and must end with `.h`. If match, first part (containing leading space, but potentialy empty if 0 times) have to be followed by `/abspath/`, than with second part.

**Older**

Do this not work?

**Edit** Modified for Mac:

```
sed 's/ \([^/ ][^ ]\{1,99\}\.h\)/ \/abspath\/\1/;' testfile.txt
```

Work same on mac and on Linux. I've replaced `+` by `{1,99}`.

Sorry, I've not rightly read the question. This work fine on both:

```
sed 's/^\([^/ ][^ ]\{1,99\}\.h\)/\/abspath\/\1/;
     s/ \([^/ ][^ ]\{1,99\}\.h\)/ \/abspath\/\1/;' testfile.txt
```

Comment: tested your edit.  Lines 4-6 were unchanged. lines 1-3 were correct.

Comment: A new edition present a version that work for whole job, on Mac *and* on Linux

Comment: Yes, this is working, thanks.  Can you explain some of the key parts?  Why did you have to mostly duplicate a new `s` command?

Comment: Like @sudo_O, the command is duplified, because I've no success whith the `or` which could be written: `s/^\(.* \|\)...` for matching two cases: 1: part is located at middle of line but preceded by a space. And 2: part is located at begin of line.

Comment: Like @sudo_O, I would appreciate a sugar (+1) if you find this helpful.

Comment: @F.Hauri good work +1... I think `sed -E 's/^(.* )?([^/][^ ]+\.h)/\1\/abspath\/\2/' file` is cleaner/shorter/easier to read `:]`

Comment: @F.Hauri just thought one downside to this solution is multiple matches per line but I don't think this is an issue for the OP.

Comment: @sudo_O: I've wrote `{0,1}` instead of `?` because of `+` previously tried and that won't work on Mac's sed and for which I already use `{1,99}`. But your'e right: `?` work fine on both. :-p

Comment: @F.Hauri `+` is part of ERE so you need the `-E` option, tested on Mac and it works fine, I added it to my answer and credit you.

Comment: @NoahR Have you tested with multiple match per line?

Comment: your second Mac targeted answer works for multi-match per line.  Top line answer does not, as you point out. The top-line answer by @sudo_O also works for multi-match.  i'm going to edit my question and test case to reflect this more inclusive scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed "s|\([^\s]*\.h\)|/abspath/\1|" <testfile.txt
```

And to ignore absolute paths:

```
sed "s|^\([^/][^\s]*\.h\)|/abspath/\1|" <testfile.txt
```

Comment: Overmatches, this does the replacement on lines 2 and 3 (plus redirection isn't needed).